# Why does the DOM remain unchanged, even though the console outputs what the correct result should be when trying to change link attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, https

```
function makeLinks(context, url) {
    var sets = context ? $(context + ' a') : $('a'),
        prot = url || window.location.protocol;
    if(prot.match(/https/)){
        lockup(sets);
    }

    function lockup(elem) {
        elem.each(function(){
            var self = $(this), 
                href = self.attr('href');
            if(href.match(/http[^s]/)){

                // This logs the correct output
                console.log(href.replace('http','https'));

                // This fails
                href.replace('http','https');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The purpose of the function is to check the current protocol of the window object.
If it is 'https:', then I want the anchors that have a href of 'http' to be 'https'.

The function is called like this: makeLinks('#wrapper', 'https:');
The second parameter is just for testing, otherwise it would use window.location.protocol

Currently, when I call this function on markup that looks like this:

```
<a href="http://cross-origin-denial.com"></a>
<a href="http://pleasesecureme.com"></a>
<a href="https://imcool.com"></a>

<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="http://cross-origin-denial.com"></a>
    <a href="http://imscrewed.com"></a>
    <a href="http://yougotmetoo.com"></a>
    <a href="https://imcool.com"></a>
</div>
```

The console logs exactly what I want to happen, however, the actual href remains unchanged inside of the DOM.

I've tested this out in Chrome and Firefox with the same result
I'm pretty sure that my logic is wrong somewhere (or everywhere)
If someone can help me understand why, I would be very appreciative :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the result of the `.replace()`.

You need to set the new value.

```
  self.attr('href', href.replace('http','https'));
```

---

or a nicer way is like this:

```
function lockup(elem) {
    elem.attr('href', function(i, href) {
        return href.match(/http[^s]/) ? href.replace('http','https') : href;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now I know how to use the .attr() callback function, and that is definitely nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Should this not be something Like Below
            if(href.match(/http[^s]/)){

```
            // This logs the correct output
            console.log(href.replace('http','https'));

            // This fails
            href.replace('http','https');
        }
    });
```

Change to:

```
    if(href.indexOf('https') == -1) {
       console.log(href.replace('http','https'));

       href.replace('http', 'https');

    }
```

Comment: Can you help me understand the benefit of that over using the regex?  My way of thinking was that I needed to make sure http was there, but not followed by an 's'.  But I guess all hrefs will be one or the other... so does it matter?

Comment: regex version is great but, has drawback on speed...think of it this way...In this version your evaluating all links regardless and either they are https or http.  Using a regular expression while acceptable will have to process each and every link each and everytime.  Great in some cases though, not in all.  Pattern and string matching takes longer.  Always doing one or the other all the time if your condition matches is a easier and less overhead.  Plus, look at it...much easier to understand.  :)

Comment: Actually, I'd say the regex is easier to understand, because for me it's easier to remember a pattern than it is to remember what the return value is supposed to be for indexOf (even though I know it pretty well).  But I didn't think about the performance cost, which could be pretty high on a lot of links, so that's a good enough reason to switch for me.